# FCM integration with Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am stuck here trying to fetch FCM token in my Xamarin native iOS project. I've researched a lot on this but all the articles are old and those methods are deprecated. I've tried the below approach as mentioned in the docs:

1. https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/ios-implementation

   ```
   private void GetFCMToken(NSData apnsToken)
   {

       var projectId = "xxxxx"; //from console
       var scope = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.ScopeFirebaseMessaging;
       var options = new NSDictionary(
                new NSString("apns_token"), apnsToken,
                new NSString("apns_sandbox"), new NSString("0")
       );

       Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.GetToken(projectId, scope, options, (string token, NSError err) =>
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fcmToken" + token);
           Console.WriteLine($"Firebase registration token: {token}");
       });
   }
   ```

   All I get here is error `{The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 1006.)}`

GetFCMToken() is being called once I receive the APNS Token data in **RegisteredForRemoteNotifications**

2. Implemented IMessagingDelegate in AppDelgate:

   ```
   public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
   public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
   ```

I was able to fetch the token in the first method initially, but it stopped altogether.

Which approach to follow as there is too much confusion and what I am doing wrong.

Pardon my formatting. Apologies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md

Comment: Yes, I have tried the approach of implementing the IMessagingDelegate, but a weird problem is happening when I am keeping breakpoints in this line "Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;". I am getting the fcm token in the method public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken), without breakpoints it doesn't seem to work. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you give me steps to reproduce!